# Minimize GitHub upload of codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, github

I am using Codeigniter with composer and want to upload all the things to github. When pushing to github the system folder also gets uploaded. As it is reproducible with composer. How do I remove it from github upload to minimize the fingerprint and reproduce it again when pull to live server.

Also tell me the steps to configure composer and how to reproduce the system folder.

Whole idea is to keep less redundant and reproducible code on the github.

Composer.json

```
{
    "description": "The CodeIgniter framework",
    "name": "codeigniter/framework",
    "type": "project",
    "homepage": "https://codeigniter.com",
    "license": "MIT",
    "support": {
            "forum": "http://forum.codeigniter.com/",
            "wiki": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki",
            "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/codeigniter",
            "source": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter"
    },
    "require": {
            "php": ">=5.2.4"
    },
    "suggest": {
            "paragonie/random_compat": "Provides better randomness in PHP 5.x"
    },
    "require-dev": {
            "mikey179/vfsStream": "1.1.*"
}
```

Using AWS.

Comment: add it to .gitignore

Comment: You can read more on `.gitignore` on https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Yes I can add it, but then when I download it on server how can I get back all the system files. Plus how to reproduce system folder after pulling?